# chromium on computer but never installed

Tags: chromium

Chromium just appeared on my windows laptop. I never installed it. It always opens automatically when I turn my laptop on. I have tried getting rid of it. I get a message back that it is already uninstalled but it is still there.

Comment: Go with these http://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you may have become victim of an adware virus.

I would suggest to run a full anti-virus scan. Personally I find the best combo to be [MalwareBytes](https://www.malwarebytes.org/) and [ADWCleaner](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/adwcleaner/).

Failing these, using a full uninstall software package may resolve the fact you are unable to get rid of the software. You could try [Revo Uninstaller](http://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) or [CCleaner](https://www.piriform.com/ccleaner/download) for this

Answer (score 0):

Chromium doesn't have a separate uninstaller as far as I have ever seen but the Free Version of [**Revo Uninstaller**](http://www.revouninstaller.com/start_freeware_download.html) might work.  Use the Advanced Uninstall option so it gets all the leftovers.

Chromium installs to several locations other than ProgramFiles(X86).  I would try using a search utility like '[Everything](http://www.voidtools.com/downloads/)' or similar.  Windows Search will get you there but slower.  Search for "Chrom*.*". (because Chrome uses "Chrome" in some places, Chromium in others).  You probably have items in \User\AppData\local\Google\ as well as others.  To see these, you need to enable viewing of hidden files.

Last option would be using Windows **regedit**' to remove the entries but I would not recommend that unless you have experience with modifying the Windows registry.  Be sure to make a backup of the registry before trying to tweak anything in it.

Answer (score 0):

As an aspiring security researcher, I have noticed an increased amount of fake Chromium browsers appearing on the web recently. You should definitely remove Chromium code-based browser if it uses one of these names: Chroomium; WebDiscover; Chedot; Outfire Browser; eFast; Tortuga; IQA Browser; Ghokswa Browser; Chromodo; Kometa Browser; Olcinium Browser; Tesla Browser; Securor; Super Browser; Torch. More @ [Chromium review](https://www.2-spyware.com/review-chromium.html).
Of course, you can notice that the amount of legitimate Chromium versions is growing as well. However, I think that all these promises to improve users' privacy and improve their being on the web are used just to trick people..